# Is -tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: mandatory?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

In [NSTableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDataSource/tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:), the overview says that `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is "required".

Right next to this, it says that `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` is required for "cell-based tables only", which suggests the person writing this document knew about view-based tables, and that `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` is required for view-based tables.

The documentation for the method `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` itself says:

> **Note**: This method is mandatory unless your application is using Cocoa bindings for providing data to the table view.

but unlike other methods makes no mention of being unnecessary for view-based tables.

And yet, if it is required, I can't figure out what it's used for.  If so, what's the relationship between that and `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`, which also takes a table, column, and row, and returns the thing to display there?

In some brief testing, it looks like NSTableView will use `-tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` if it's defined, and if not, it'll use `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:`.  If they're both defined, it calls them both, but only uses the former for display.

If I'm writing a view-based NSTableView, is there any reason to implement this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, despite all of the documentation saying that it is "mandatory" and "required", the NSTableView.h header file says:

> This method is required for the "Cell Based" TableView, and is optional for the "View Based" TableView.

If you implement `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` to do all the necessary work to display your data, you don't need to implement the other method.

The header file also says why you might implement it for view-based tables:

> If implemented in the latter case, the value will be set to the view at a given row/column if the view responds to -setObjectValue: (such as NSControl and NSTableCellView).

This doesn't seem any easier than just implementing it in the normal view-based method, though, so it seems more like an upgrade-compatibility feature than something you'd actually want to use in a new application.